# javascript calling a function after getting https.request response (but not as its callback)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Beginner question. I have the following function that makes a https.request. When the data arrives, I am passing it to a callback function `myData`. **(updated wording)**

Once the `myData` is updated only then, I want to make call to `myCallBack1`. ... **but not inside** the function call back for `response.on`

**Can some one please give me an example on how to do this?**

```
function test(myCallBack1) {

   var myOut = https.request(opts, 
     function(response) {
         console.log("response is:", response);
         // I don't want to directly send mycallBack1. 
         // instead capture the data in myData
         response.on('data', myData);      
     });        

    // Now I want to call myCallBack1 and give it value of myData. 
    // how do I ensure that the myCallBack() function is executed 
    // only after 
    // response.on('data', myData) is executed? 

};
```

Comment: Why you just won't try call myCallBack1() after   response.on('data', myData);  ?

Comment: The problem is, it won't wait until getting response.on('data', myData) is finished.. In other words, if I call it after this line, it may get executed even before the myData is updated,

Comment: What kind of JS framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The `resonse.on` signature is `event, callback` where the `event` is event name and `callback` is callback function. So this will work:

```
response.on('data', function(myData) {
   // Do something with the data
   myCallBack1();
});
```

Comment: thanks, sure it will work, but I want some way to do it outside of response.on.. the code is getting too complex to read otherwise. In the example myData is a function in itself

Comment: Oh, the `myData` is a function. Please improve the post, so that it's clear.
There is no way around calling the callback as you have no way to detect when `myData` gets a value and react on that.
You can improve readability by creating inline functions, which separate functionality or you may want to use Async (https://github.com/caolan/async) that would improve readability a bit and enable you to maintain callback hell to some extent. I also suggest you get familiar with Promises - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.

Comment: yes it is the calback hell i am worried about.. becomes tough to understand the code.  Is there a way to know that https.request is finished .. tried on.('end',..)  but not working

Comment: The `.on('finish')` would work? https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish
But that about as good as handling all in `.on('data')`. Take a look at the Async package or Promises, that would help with callback hell.

Comment: thank you, yes it gets executed but unfortunately before on('data')

Comment: Oh well, I'm out of ideas besides Async and Promises to solve the callback hells.